# Close button and animation effect loading with page instead of loading on click

Tags: jquery, html, css

**close button loading with page instead of load with modal element 
**
*animation effect loading with page instead of loading with image,loading first effect with out selecting the image*

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.button').on('click', function(){
    var target = $(this).attr('rel');
    $("."+target).show().siblings("div").hide();
  });
});

function myFunction(imgs) {
  var expandImg = document.getElementById("expandedImg");
  var imgText = document.getElementById("imgtext");
  expandImg.src = imgs.src;
  imgText.innerHTML = imgs.alt;
  expandImg.parentElement.style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
.closebtn {
  color: white;
  float: right;
  font-size: 43px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  top: -78px;
  right: 219px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.pulse {
  animation: pulse 4s ;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: table;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  -webkit-animation-name: pulse;
  animation-name: pulse;
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  }
}


**js script for the button and close , image  **
```

```html
<div class="container pulse">
  <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="closebtn">&times;</span>
  <img id="expandedImg" class="popupimg_style ">
  <div id="imgtext"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you please provide a running example

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/eLtv68u9/   path for the jsfiddle where i kept complete code

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/eLtv68u9/  .. path for js fiddle where i kept the complete code of page

Comment: Muzamil301 - jsfiddle.net/eLtv68u9  runnig code is in here

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/eLtv68u9/10/ please check this updated fiddle done with loading of close button but i couldn't get the animation issue

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/eLtv68u9/12/  flow this link you can see bro..  modal not working here i dotn understand y

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/eLtv68u9/12/  follow this link you can bro. you can see close button, but modal popup not working here y i dont understand

Comment: you want to implement pulse animation on modal right?

Comment: here is the updated fiddle , i have commented the extra code in html now there is  no extra close button in tabs https://jsfiddle.net/eLtv68u9/19/

Comment: if you comment the that div how the pulse and the image modal popup will work.the issue here is close button is loading before and image pulse has to start after the image is click but it loading for first time with out selecting, from second time its works fine